# Stream not receiving data after using InputStream read()

Tags: java, io, stream

I came across a problem related to I/O while developing a simple application and I am not sure why my code is not working properly. I took only the part of the code which is not working and made a simple example.

**Server Class**

```
public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ServerSocket serversocket = new ServerSocket(56700);
        Socket socket = serversocket.accept();
        InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        while (true) {
            String line;
            if ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                System.out.println(line);

                switch (line) {
                    case "line":
                        System.out.println(br.readLine());
                        break;

                    case "file": {

                        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("file.txt"))) {

                            byte[] bytes = new byte[4096];

                            int count;
                            while ((count = is.read(bytes)) > 0) {
                                fos.write(bytes, 0, count);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Client Class**

```
public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 56700);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());

        pw.write("line\n");
        pw.write("line test\n");
        pw.flush();

        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("test.txt")); OutputStream fos = socket.getOutputStream()) {

            pw.write("file\n");
            pw.flush();

            byte[] bytes = new byte[4096];
            int count;
            while ((count = fis.read(bytes)) > 0) {
                fos.write(bytes, 0, count);
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error sending the file.");
        }

        pw.write("\n");
        pw.write("line\n");
        pw.write("line test 2\n");
        pw.flush();

    }
}
```

Basically, I have a client which is sending data to a server. The client uses `PrintWriter write(String str)` to write a line before the data of interest, to identify the type of information sent: a line of text or a file. As you see, the server reads the lines of text with `BufferedReader readLine()` and the bytes from the file with `InputStream read(byte[] bytes)`. The client first sends a line of text, then data from a file as bytes and finally a line of text again.

The thing is that after the file is sent and received by the server successfully, it doesn't receive the line of text. I checked and realized that the BufferedReader never receives this line of text. As you can see, I wrote a `\n` after the file data is written, in case that was the problem, but it didn't work. I am probably missing something related to the functioning of these streams.

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in this code:

```
try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("test.txt")); OutputStream fos = socket.getOutputStream()) {

    pw.write("file\n");
    pw.flush();

    byte[] bytes = new byte[4096];
    int count;
    while ((count = fis.read(bytes)) > 0) {
        fos.write(bytes, 0, count);
    }

} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println("Error sending the file.");
}
```

You use try-finally with `OutputStream fos = socket.getOutputStream()`, after exit from try-finally block of code you program close `socket.getOutputStream()` because try-finally always call `close` method in implicit `finally` block. You `PrintWriter` use same `SocketOutputStream` here:

```
pw.write("\n");
pw.write("line\n");
pw.write("line test 2\n");
pw.flush();
```

But this stream already closed.

Try this:

```
OutputStream fos = socket.getOutputStream()
try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("test.txt"))) {

    pw.write("file\n");
    pw.flush();

    byte[] bytes = new byte[4096];
    int count;
    while ((count = fis.read(bytes)) > 0) {
        fos.write(bytes, 0, count);
    }

} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println("Error sending the file.");
}

pw.write("\n");
pw.write("line\n");
pw.write("line test 2\n");
pw.flush();
pw.close(); //closing PrintWriter and internal SocketOutputStream
```

It will better, if you'll user only one: PrintWriter or OutputStream